# Summary on Non-Deep-Learning based Graph Machine Learning Algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, graph-theory, graph-neural-network

I have a classification task for predicting some node attributes, and I would like to find some machine learning algorithms that can be applied to graph data, and are not deep-learning or neural network based methods. I searched around review and survey papers on this field, but can only find deep-learning based methods mostly graph neural networks. Can someone help me to find a summary on other machine learning algorithms or how to apply conventional machine learning algorithms to such data? Thanks